# Problems with Login/Logout Session

Tags: php, jquery, session, caching, authentication

I am attempting to make a login system, that depending on the type of login, will display a different page. (I.e logged in as admin, or various other roles)

This consists of three files:

**Login.php** - various forms are submitted here, and depending on the form value names, sets a session variable to the correct level (admin etc)

**Logout.php** - Unsets the previously mentioned variable.

**Dashboard.php** - Checks to see if the variable is set, if so, load the relevent information, if not, send back to index.php

Please find below the code:

**Login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['uname_driver']))
{
    $username = $_POST['uname_driver'];
    $hpassword = password_hash($_POST['hpass_driver'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    // Check here for login details within server
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = "driver";
    header("Location: dashboard.php");
}
if (isset($_POST['uname_restaurant']))
{
    $username = $_POST['uname_restaurant'];
    $hpassword = password_hash($_POST['hpass_restaurant'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    // Check here for login details within server
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = "restaurant";
    header("Location: dashboard.php");
}
if (isset($_POST['uname_admin']))
{
    $username = $_POST['uname_admin'];
    $hpassword = password_hash($_POST['hpass_admin'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    // Check here for login details within server
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = "admin";
    header("Location: dashboard.php");
}
```

**Logout.php** *- Edited to reflect Juned's answer that solved one part of the problem*

```
<?php 
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();


header("Location: index.php");
```

**Dashboard.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include("header.php");
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']))
{
    switch ($_SESSION['loggedIn'])
    {
        case "admin":
            include("admin_dashboard.php");
            break;
        case "driver":
            include("driver_dashboard.php");
            break;
        case "restaurant":
            include("restaurant_dashboard.php");
            break;
    }
}
else
{
    header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

Logging in appears to work absolutely fine, until I attempt to log **out** again, logging out is achieved with an onclick event of a certain button on the dashboard and a Jquery post, like so:

```
$('#logoutOfDashboard').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var reallyLogout=confirm("Do you really want to log out?");
    if(reallyLogout)
    {
        $.post('logout.php', {})
        .done(function(data)
        { 
            window.location.replace("/");
        })
    }
});
```

Again, this appears to work, however if I manually enter /dashboard.php into the URL bar, it kicks me back to index.php as expected. **Now** whenever the login form is submitted, and the session variable should be recreated, dashboard.php continuously kicks back to index, as if it isn't there and I can no longer login during this session. It's almost as if the session variable is caching on unset and can never be re-set

I have attempted adding in various no-caching header info such as:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

But this appears to have no effect. Any assistance or insight in this would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

**Index.php**

```
<?php
include("header.php");
?>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Website Coming Soon!</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="row marketing">
            <div class="col-lg-6 center-block">
                <a class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-space center-block" href="/restaurant_login.php" role="button">Log In As Restaurant</a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6 center-block">
                <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-space center-block" href="/driver_login.php" role="button">Log In As Driver</a>
            </div>
        </div>


        <footer class="footer">
            <p>&copy; 2016</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Header.php**

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
require_once('config.php');
require_once('functions.php');
function autoloader($class)
{
    require_once(PUBLIC_BASE_PATH_PHP . "classes/$class.php");
}

spl_autoload_register("autoloader");

global $dbConn;
$dbConn = null;

if(!Database::connect())
{
    die("Unable to connect to the database");
}
?>

<head>
    <!-- Footer these scripts at end -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Merge these together and minify at end -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jumbotron-narrow.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/signin.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
```

**RestarauntLogin.php**

```
<?php Header("Cache-Control: max-age=3000, must-revalidate");
include("header.php");
?>

<div class="container">
  <form class="form-signin" action="/login.php" method="post">

    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>

    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name = "uname_restaurant" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>

    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name = "hpass_restaurant" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    <a href = "/" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" role="button">Back</a>

  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: I believe the problem is that Session is unset after page reloaded, because PHP is backend system and it is not dynamic it leads to $_SESSION still be set until window is reloaded, meaning if you dynamically load window through jQuery it will still say you are logged in

Comment: Should read up on how sessions and session cookies work and don't see why you even use ajax for logging out since you do a redirect anyway which would be better handled at server

Comment: I have tried removing all Jquery for the logout, and just having an href that sends the user to logout.php (with an extra header(Location: index.php) at the end of logout.php) with the same effect.

Answer (score 4):

I tried to creating a local test page from my computer using your codes. It seems to be working fine. What I could suggest if you're dealing with sessions and cookies and you made a lot of testing or debugging which will sometimes mess up the browser. Try clearing your cache/cookies. I meant to put this in a comment section but I don't have enough reputation :) But if this didn't help, please tell me and I'll have it deleted.

Comment: Hi Roljhon, This absolutely did help, It's nice to know that I am not going mad, and that this is a weird issue and not me just being stupid. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that fixed the issue buddy. Happy to help :) It did made me crazy before thinking what the hell is really happening :D But anyway, goodluck buddy!

Comment: Unfortunately I still have the issue, but the fact you tested it locally and it seems to work makes me feel a lot better :P, Perhaps shifting to another server may solve my issue alltogether. +1 from me :)

Comment: Great! but what server you're using anyway? :)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have access to all the details (i'm not providing the hosting unfortunately), just a standard linux box I think with cpanel and apache. However checking it using "builtwith.com" shows that it is using some kind of caching system called "Varnish" that I am not famililar with, I wonder if this is the culprit

Comment: I'm not pretty sure if that caching system would matter, but try to run it locally and if you couldn't replicate the issue, then it's really your server messing it around :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to destroy the session, so instead of just unsetting $_SESSION["loggedin"], you need to completely destroy the session by eating the session cookie. PHP has a built in function to do this for you: session_destroy();

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

```
<?php
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
?>
```

Comment: I have tried using this (changing the unset to a session_destroy) as well as trying both, but with exactly the same result.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, this does appear to solve one of the problems! :) Now after logging out, if the user attempts to access /dashboard.php again, it will correctly kick them back to index. however I still have the issue with being unable to log back in again afterwards..

Comment: Sure, please give me a few minutes

Comment: I have edited with all of the extra code you might be interested in

Comment: What I would try is, first remove all the headers you've added, they are not necessary. Then on the page where you've got your login form HTML code, add session_start() to the top of that so you've got a sessionid before the form is submitted. Shouldn't really make a difference but I'm guessing it's a server issue??? Apart from that, I'm stumped. Everything else looks like it should work.

Comment: Thanks for continuously helping, but unfortunately I am still experiencing the same issue... I am starting to think that there is some kind of weird server stuff going on, I will test on another server and see if the same happens. If nobody comes up with a functioning solution by the end of the bounty, I will of course, award it to you :)

Comment: What does this part mean? "// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!"

How would the above script have to change if I did: ini_set('session.name', 'new_php_session_name');

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, the main problem happening here is maintaining session throughout the system.

I have written a simple code for login system which I believe help to understand that. Before looking into the Aphire's code, I would like to mention that there is no point to use Ajax in the code because lastly there is a page refresh so it would be good if you redirect your user to directly on logout.php.

Anyway, please see the code given below which would certainly help to understand the session use in login system.

**login.php**

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']))
{
    header("Location: dashboard.php");
} else {
    if (isset($name))
    {
            $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = $name;
            header("Location: dashboard.php");
    } else {
        echo "Please provide correct input";
    }
}
?>
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php 
// Initialize the session.
session_start();

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();


header("Location: login.php");
?>
```

**dashboard.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']))
{
    switch ($_SESSION['loggedIn'])
    {
        case "admin":
            echo "admin";
            break;
        case "driver":
            echo "driver";
            break;
        case "restaurant":
            echo "restaurant";
            break;
    default:
        header("Location: login.php");
        session_destroy();
    }
}
else
{
    header("Location: login.php");
}
?>

<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
```

Comment: Hi Harsh, thanks very much for the code snippets, I have in fact removed the AJAX from the logout and taken some of the code from the snippets and intergrated it into mine, however I have the same issue :(

Comment: Hi Aphire, Can you please share the code you have updated so that I can look into it ?

Comment: Hi Harsh, I am still developing on it at the moment, I will edit my question as soon as I can I have something stable that isn't going to change for a while. Thanks very much for sticking with it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `window.location.replace()`,   try using `window.location.href='/'`

Comment: Same issue i'm afraid, thanks for the attempt though!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to keep the session id, but just delete the session data? I guess there is no point to delete the session id.

I'm talking about removing this piece of code from `logout.php`:

```
// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
```

So, `logout.php` now looks like:

```
<?php 
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

header("Location: index.php");
```

That should be enough to "logout" the user.

Comment: This is how I had it originally, and I have just tested it again. Unfortunately doing this allows the user to still access /dashboard.php after logging out, until they control + F5 (reset cache). and after that, the issue with being unable to log in and recreate the session still occurs as normal :(

Comment: So it looks like you have a cache problem, and no problem with the session.
Probably, after that, when you login again and it looks to fail, if you also press CTRL+F5, you get into the dashboard again.

Comment: Also, you mentioned you've tried to send cache related headers on your header.php file, but that file isn't used by login.php and logout.php, so the browser may be caching the redirects on these responses. I would create a cache.php file (just to test) and put a cache header there: 

`Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate`

The include that file from ALL other php files you have.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have tried adding in the cache.php, but unfortunately I have the exact same issue. When I check the site with builtwith.com I noticed that there is something called Varnish on the site, which is a caching tool, I imagine this is causing the issue, unfortunately I don't run the server, or have SSH access, so I will need to contact the hosting provider and ask them to remove it. Thanks again for your response!

Answer (score 0):

I created a small version from your snippets & tried it on my localhost as happened with [Roljhon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41511892/2743887)

Everything seems to be working fine. I think there may be a problem with the other code OR your server configurations. I can not tell.

In case it may help, here is the code that I tested with:

**loginForm.php**

```
<?php
Header("Cache-Control: max-age=3000, must-revalidate");
//include("header.php");
?>
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-signin" action="login.php" method="post">
    <input type="email" name = "uname_restaurant" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
    <input type="password" name = "hpass_restaurant" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['uname_restaurant']))
{
    $username = $_POST['uname_restaurant'];
    $hpassword = password_hash($_POST['hpass_restaurant'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = "restaurant";
}
var_dump($_SESSION);
die("Location: dashboard.php");
```

**dashboard.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
//include("header.php");
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']))
{
    switch ($_SESSION['loggedIn'])
    {
        case "admin":
            die("admin_dashboard.php");
            break;
        case "driver":
            die("driver_dashboard.php");
            break;
        case "restaurant":
            die("restaurant_dashboard.php");
            break;
    }
}
else
{
    die("Location: index.php");
}
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php 
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();

die("Location: index.php");
```